# How do you create a program that checks how many txt files in the folder?

Tags: c#

How do you create a program that checks how many txt files in the folder?
I have program and i need to see how many txt files in that folder how can i do it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var fileCount = Directory
                   .EnumerateFiles("filepath", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   .Count();
```

Comment: Lol. I was just trying to post about that. Stupid trains have no signal. :) +1

Comment: thanks man i just strated to learn programing and i do not know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 DirectoryInfo finfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\sample"); // path            
 FileInfo[] Files = finfo.GetFiles("*.txt"); //file type
 int fileCount = Files.Length; // getting count
```